Uniqueness results for linear first order systems of PDEs
Context: I have the following system of PDEs, for an unknown function $u:\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\to \mathbb{C}^m$ (it is a system in the components of $u$):
$$u_{x_0}=\sum_{i=1}^n A_iu_{x_i} + B(x)u\qquad u(0,x_1,\ldots, x_n)=0$$
where $A_i$'s are constant $m\times m$ matrices with complex entries and $B(x)$ is a $\mathcal{C}^\infty$ matrix-valued function (again $m\times m$).
Goal: I would like to conclude that $u\equiv 0$ (at least locally around the origin or locally in $x_0$).
Attempts: I know that, if $B(x)$ is an analytic function, then Holmgren's uniqueness theorem gives me the desired conclusion; inspecting the proof of Holmgren's result, analyticity is used only in saying that the system
$$-v_{x_0}+\sum_{i=1}^n A_iv_{x_i}= B(x)v\qquad v\vert_S=f$$
has a solution whenever $S$ is a non-characteristic hypersurface and $f$ a continuous function (for example, $S$ could be a sphere with center $(-c,0,\ldots, 0)$ and radius $c+r$).
I tried searching through the literature, but I'm no expert in the field and I either find results for constant coefficients ($B(x)$ constant) or specific results for scalar function in the quasilinear case.

You might be in luck and, depending on the properties of the $A_i$ matrices, your system might be of strict or symmetric hyperbolic type. But more information about $A_i$ is needed to check that.

Matrices $A_i$ depend on $n$ (also $m$ is in fact $m(n)$) - they come from some multiplication operators in a Clifford algebra. I can compute (with some coding) them for given $n$, but I don't see any reasonably well-behaved expression.
They are not symmetric and there is no immediate reason for which the eigenvalues of any linear combination should be all distinct (let alone all real).
My hope is that having the first-order part with constant coefficients could give some extra information.
The hyperbolic case would give also existence results, which I am not requesting.
